# translate menu item using entity translation

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I am kind of confused and really need some guidance
Is there a way to translate menu items using entity translation?(One item for all languages)
Thanks

Comment: i am aware of that option but when I translate my menu items I end up getting more than one link per menu items depending on how many languages are enabled.

Comment: Please read the document I have posted "LINK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Drupal core alone, user-defined menu items are not translatable. The Menu translation module, part of the i18n package, allows users to select a translation mode for each menu.
**[LINK](https://www.drupal.org/node/1113982)**

Comment: would'nt this way produce multiple menu items?

Comment: @redamakarem why bother if each copy is only visible in it's language?

Comment: i have lots of menu items with 3 to 4 levels so there will be loads of them. I just wanted to know if there was a way thats all

Answer (score 1):

Use the `entity_translation_i18n_menu` submodule of [Entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation).

> Allows menu items to be translated on the entity form.

It has good integration with the `i18n_menu` module.